# Is this statement linked with the following result on linear forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, convex-geometry

Here is the result on linear forms :

> Let consider $\psi,\psi_1,...,\psi_p$, $\ p+1$ linear forms on $E$ a
> $\mathbb{K}$-vector space of finite or infinite dimension. Then the following conditions are equivalent :
>
> $\bullet $$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^p \ker(\psi_i)\subset \ker(\psi)$.
>
> $\bullet$ $\psi \in \text{span}\{\psi_1,...,\psi_p\}$.

Now here is the statement :

> Let consider the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x,x_1,...x_p$ be vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the following conditions are equivalent :
>
> $\bullet$ $x\in \text{span}\{x_1,...,x_p\}$ and the coefficients of the linear combination are nonnegative.
>
> $\bullet$ for all $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\forall i \in \{1,...,p\}, \ \langle h,x_i\rangle \ge 0$ we also have $\langle h,x\rangle\ge 0$.

Moreover if someone has references about it and these kind of results, it would be great !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is $a$ in the last statement?

Comment: These statements are related in spirit, since with an inner product every vector $x$ corresponds to a linear functional $\varphi(y) := \langle x, y \rangle$. However, the second statement is saying something stronger about positivity which makes sense only over $\mathbb{R}$ rather than a general field. I assume that $a$ is a typo for $x$: then the first set there is the convex cone $\sum_i \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} x_i$ of the $x_i$, and the second set is the intersection of the half-planes $\langle -, x_i \rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My mistake it is $x$ !

Comment: @Joppy Thank you nice remark ! For the resolution of the statement apparently it is linked with Helly's theorem on convex set !

Comment: As @Joppy said, they are related in spirit. In the kernel case, $E$ and $E^*$ are involved, in the second case it is just $E$ ($\mathbb{R}^n$ in this case). Note that the second case is basically saying that if $A,B$ are closed, convex cones, then $A \subset B$ **iff** $B^* \subset A^*$, essentially a duality result.